# Why my nginx server receives requests targeting ads.yahoo.com?

Tags: nginx, logging

I have a nginx proxy facing public internet. A few days ago, I started to receive a torrential amount of requests, targeting URLs that are invalid for my domain.

An excerpt from nginx access.log:

```
216.245.222.172 - - [07/Feb/2014:10:45:26 +0000] "GET http://ads.yahoo.com/st?ad_type=iframe&ad_size=300x250&section=5306841&pub_url=${PUB_URL} HTTP/1.0" 301 184 "http://www.echogap.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=1383:Credit-Report---How-Do-Late-Payments-Affect-My-Credit-Report-And-Score?&catid=154" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; PPC Mac OS X; en) AppleWebKit/125.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Safari/125.8"
```

Some points I need help understanding / solving:

- Why does the request url contains the full url with domain name, instead of the usual path only ?
- How is it possible that requests that are not even targeting my domain reaches my server (.i.e, ads.yahoo.com) ?
- What would be the best way to avoid serving these requests ? I guess blacklisting the originated ips is out of question, since the requests come from a LOT of different addresses.
- Does the described scenario mean an explicit attack ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems like they are trying to use your web server as an [open proxy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_proxy). As long as you don't see your servers responding with a `200 OK`, you shouldn't be worried.

UPDATE:

Although there may be ways to handle this with builtin nginx functionality, I found easier to install/enable [mod_security](http://www.modsecurity.org/projects/modsecurity/nginx/) and let him handle this and other nasty attacks. As you'll see in the logs below, somebody is trying to reach wikipedia through my server, mod_security knows that this this is an anomaly an takes an appropriate action (It returns a 403 forbidden response). This is an Apache server but it should be exactly the same in nginx.

```
--817ee627-A--
[03/Feb/2014:22:26:01 +0300] Uu-tScDjiOsAAALeENQAAAAA 178.19.107.26 52735 1.2.3.4 80
--817ee627-B--
GET http://wikipedia.pl HTTP/1.1
Host: wikipedia.pl
Accept: */*
Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive

--817ee627-F--
HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
Content-Length: 202
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1

--817ee627-E--

--817ee627-H--
Message: Access denied with code 403 (phase 1). Match of "rx ^(?i:(?:[a-z]{3,10}\\s+(?:\\w{3,7}?://[\\w\\-\\./]*(?::\\d+)?)?/[^?#]*(?:\\?[^#\\s]*)?(?:#[\\S]*)?|connect (?:\\d{1,3}\\.){3}\\d{1,3}\\.?(?::\\d+)?|options \\*)\\s+[\\w\\./]+|get /[^?#]*(?:\\?[^#\\s]*)?(?:#[\\S]*)?)$" against "REQUEST_LINE" required. [file "/etc/httpd/modsecurity.d/activated_rules/modsecurity_crs_20_protocol_violations.conf"] [line "52"] [id "960911"] [rev "2"] [msg "Invalid HTTP Request Line"] [data "GET http://wikipedia.pl HTTP/1.1"] [severity "WARNING"] [ver "OWASP_CRS/2.2.6"] [maturity "9"] [accuracy "9"] [tag "OWASP_CRS/PROTOCOL_VIOLATION/INVALID_REQ"] [tag "CAPEC-272"]
Action: Intercepted (phase 1)
Stopwatch: 1391455561096692 260049 (- - -)
Stopwatch2: 1391455561096692 260049; combined=104238, p1=104194, p2=0, p3=0, p4=0, p5=43, sr=104028, sw=1, l=0, gc=0
Response-Body-Transformed: Dechunked
Producer: ModSecurity for Apache/2.7.3 (http://www.modsecurity.org/); OWASP_CRS/2.2.6.
Server: Apache
Engine-Mode: "ENABLED"
```

*1.2.3.4 = I replaced my IP address with this fake IP. I don't need any more strange packets knocking my door :)

Comment: Thanks for pointing out Gabriel. Researching on a solution on "how to avoid being an open proxy" I stumbled upon the [valid_referers](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpRefererModule) nginx directive. The way I see it, returning 403 instead of 302 on these hop-requests should make my server less appropriate for the job of being an open proxy, and maybe stop being used as such at all (please correct me if I am wrong).

Comment: Anyway, I cannot mark your answer right just yet. Some points raised on the question are still opened. Let's wait a bit longer.

Comment: You are correct, returning 403 will be the safer way to handle this. Please see the update in my reply.